# WorkItemChanged event Client Side

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For my current project I have to add a record to a database when a custom workitem changes to specific states. For this you can build a TFS plugin which fires at the WorkItemChanged Event. However our company policies don't allow us to build these plugins because it is processed for each workitem in all projectcollections. This action is only needed for a few team projects.

My question: is it possible to create some clientside plugin(perhaps a VS plugin) which fires an action on this event instead? Or is there someway to create another sort of listener to this event?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a custom control for in the WorkItem editform. Within this control I could implement all the required logic for creating the database record.

So instead of setting the combobox state to the onhold state, there now is a button which does exactly the same, executes my custom coding and thus adds a record to our database.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having TFS drive the alerts for you, you can implement a polling based alert system.

I would create a simple work item query that selected the work items you were interested in and sorted by the Changed Date column.  Then I would write a simple program that used the [TFS SDK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk) to run this work item query and notify based on the results, keeping a high water mark between polls.  (The TFS SDK samples has an example of running a work item query.)

Note that this polling-based approach has advantages over setting up a SOAP listener regardless of your corporate policy.  The SOAP-based alerts system that TFS uses was developed for communication between components of the TFS infrastructure.  It's expected that the SOAP endpoint you configure is high availability - if your machine goes down, the SOAP service crashes or your IP address changes, you'll start seeing TFS complaining in the event log.  I filled up the event log on my TFS server before I switched to a polling based model for a similar alert system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would certainly be an option for a lot of scenarios. However the record that i must process in the database, creates an Onhold start/end time, which is used for Service Level Agreements. So it has to be somewhat realtime.

Comment: Double post, apparently there is a timelimit to edit the post.

So lets say we could run this program or service every minute, we query every workitem in the collection, look if it has been set to that specific state, and if so create a new Db Record. Please correct me if I get this wrong.


Question: what if in the meanwhile the state gets reset or set to another state, is it possible to query for a list of processed states?

Comment: I see.  So you've basically got an "on hold" flag and you're querying for items that are in that state...?  It is tricky to poll for items such that you'd never miss a state change in this case.  (You could look at recently modified work items and crawl their history, but that's awfully tedious.)  Another option is to use the TFS Alerts Explorer, which allows you to configure much finer-grained alerts that your administrators may be happier with and use either SOAP or email alerts as appropriate: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Comment: Exactly, so it is possible, but far from ideal for my scenario. Thanks for the Alerts Explorer suggestion. I will look into this for future references!